# LXML разбор XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Имеется XML [тут](https://sdvk-oboi.ru/sitemap.xml). Для начала необходимо представить его в видео дерева.

```
def parse_xml(page_text):
    return etree.XML(page_text)
```

page_text - Это ответ от сервера (aiohttp)

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/sdvk-oboi.ru/sdvk-oboi.ru.py", line 80, in crawl
    urls = await future
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Git/sdvk-oboi.ru/sdvk-oboi.ru.py", line 69, in parse
    print(parse_xml(page_text))
  File "D:/Git/sdvk-oboi.ru/sdvk-oboi.ru.py", line 61, in parse_xml
    return etree.XML(page_text.text)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3192, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
ValueError: can only parse strings
```

Попробовал так `return etree.XML(page_text.text())` и так `return etree.XML(page_text.text)` все равно туже ошибку выкидывает.

Может я делаю что-то не так? Просто до этого LXML использовал только для парсинга HTML и решил почему бы им и XML не спарсить.

HTML парсил так:

```
def get_html (request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text())
```

Update:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

count_thread = os.cpu_count()
limit = asyncio.Semaphore(50)  #Количество одновременных запросов, которые были отправлены серверы, но еще не получен от них ответ. Не означает одновременную отправку 10 запросов

headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}

url_main = ["https://sdvk-oboi.ru/sitemap.xml"

async def request(client, url):
    global limit, headers
    for i in range(50):
        print(i)
        async with limit:
            try:
                async with client.get(url, headers=headers) as r:
                    log.info('Запрос: %s', url)
                    print(r.status)
                    if(r.status == 200):
                        return r
                    else:
                        log.info("Ошибка статус: %s", r.status)
                        await asyncio.sleep(i)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                await asyncio.sleep(i)
def get_html (request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text())

def parse_xml(page_text):
    return etree.XML(page_text)

def print_html(html):
    print(lxml.html.tostring(html, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))

def parse(page_text):
    urls = []
    print(get_html(page_text))
    return urls

async def crawl(future, client, pool):
    futures = []
    # Получаем из футуры ссылки
    urls = await future
    # Выгребаем для каждой ссылки разметку страницы
    for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
        # Передаём парсинг разметки в пул потоков
        parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future))
        # parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future))
        # Рекурсивно вызываем себя для парсинга новой порции ссылок
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)

async def start_main(root_urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    # Создаём пул потоков по количеству процессоров
    # with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as pool:
        # Создаём клиентскую сессию
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            # Создаём корневую футуру
            initial_future = loop.create_future()
            # Помещаем в неё ссылки, с которых начнём парсить
            initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
            # Передаём эту футуру в сопрограмму обхода ссылок
            # вместе с пулом потоков и клиентской сессией
            await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(url_main))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: А что показывает `print(type(page_text))`? Не хватает в вопросе минимального примера чтобы посмотреть ваш случай :)

Comment: @gil9red <class 'aiohttp.client_reqrep.ClientResponse'>

Comment: С асинхронным кодом почти не работал, давайте попробуем `print((await page_text).text())` или с учетом, приведенного в вопросе, кода так: `parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse_xml, (await request_future))`. А в `parse_xml` измените на `return etree.XML(page_text.text())`

Comment: parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse_xml, (await request_future)) так зачем, у нас же есть метод parse

Comment: @gil9red если я в методе request исправлю return r на return await r, то выкидывает ошибку object ClientResponse can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Не знаю зачем, примера использования `parse_xml` не нашел в вопросе, поэтому предположил что так используете. Да и `parse_xml` спокойно заменяется на `parse` -- парсер html сможет распарсить xml, хотя могут и возникнуть проблемы

Comment: @gil9red я сначала его пробовал, выкидывало ошибку TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, думал может нужно xml распарсить, но и тут ошибки

Comment: Накидал пример с aiohttp + lxml.etree.XML https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/797464a41e90cf56a00aedb699e2633ec5fdbfd9/aiohttp__asyncio__examples/hello_world__parse__lxml_etree.py

Comment: @gil9red о спасибо, я использовал HTML вместо entree и он тоже заработал). Отметьте ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю пример загрузки и парсинга url:

```
# pip install aiohttp
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from lxml import etree


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        # Возвращаем ответ в байтах
        return await response.content.read()


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        xml_str = await fetch(session, 'https://sdvk-oboi.ru/sitemap.xml')
        root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)

        for url in root.xpath('//*[local-name()="loc"]/text()'):
            print(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```